# Какие отличия между worker_threads и cluster?

Tags: node.js, cluster, worker-threads

Не совсем понятно когда применяются воркеры и какие отличия у них с кластерами?

Например я пытался сделать одновременный запуск нескольких браузеров через puppeteer, кластеры с этим справились отлично, но они ограничены количеством потоков процессора или можно выходить за их границы?

Как лучше работать и использовать их?
Не совсем понимаю принцип их работы.

Когда использовал воркеры, их видимо создавалось очень много, что вызывало утечки памяти,у меня мало опыта и поэтому я не смог определить причину и решил попробовать работать с кластерами, но стало интересно можно ли как-то использовать ещё дополнительно и воркеры, чтобы ускорить процесс выполняемой мной задач, но для этого мне хотелось бы понять в чем отличие, можно ли использовать их одновременно, ускорит ли это работу и как вообще лучше использовать данные инструменты?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html «Unlike child_process or cluster, worker_threads can share memory.»

Comment: Твои браузеры это отдельные процессы так что никакой пользы от worker_threads не будет. Собственно они в любом случае запускаются в отдельном child_process, так что и кластер никакой пользы не принесёт, только лишние накладные расходы

Comment: Ну по крайне мере обработка стала лучше, если я делал всё в одном приложении.
Когда разбил на кластеры, стало быстрее и легче, скорость значительно выросла.
Возможно если делать какую-то отдельную очередь, то эффект наверно был бы таким же.

Answer (score 1):

Из личного опыта работы c **Node.js**

*Давайте представим реку, у которой есть одно русло и по реке суда могут двигаться только последовательно и обгонять друг друга не могут...*

## Когда использовать cluster

Если есть входящий поток однотипных заданий, который не вытягивает 1 поток движка V8(читай как 1 ядро), то лучше использовать кластер.
Число дочерних процессов(cluster.fork()) рекомендуется использовать максимум MaxCpu - 1, что бы родительский процесс мог обслуживать дочерние процессы.

Таким образом вы паралеллите логику приложения на несколько потоков.

*т.е. у нашей реки появляется несколько рукавов, такой же ширины и мы можем направлять суда в эти рукава и пропускать не 1, а например 4 судна в единицу времени.*

## Когда полезны worker-threads

worker-threads(Воркеры) полезны для тяжелых и блокирующих операций.

Представьте, что вам по процессу надо отсортировать массив в 100000 записей или построить на основе массива json с множественными вложениями.
Если запустить arr.forEach процесс остановится до тех пор, пока не отработает. Если такое делать в кластере(cluster), то можно забить все дочерние процессы.

*К нашим судам на реке добавились танкеры, которые мы должны разгрузить в середине пути. Танкер останавливается и начинает разгрузку. Все остальные суда в этом русле(рукаве/потоке) ждут окончания разгрузки танкера и как танкер поплывет, все остальные суда поплывут далее.*

В этом случае на помощь приходят воркеры. Отдаем в worker-threads данные и ожидаем ответа. Ожидание не блокирует [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

*Строим для танкеров отдельную заводь и док, куда они будут заходить для разгрузки. Как разгрузятся, вернутся обратно в русло в общий поток судов.*

---

Что бы понять, что вам подходит больше и от чего будет больше пользы, Вам надо понять, от чего вы хотите избавиться и какого результата добиться.

Количество одновременно работающих worker-threads, желательно, что бы не превышало MaxCpu - 1. 
Однако, если потребление cpu не слишком велико, то можно и увеличивать их количество.

т.е. MaxCpu - 1 это общая рекомендация, а не жесткое ограничение.