# Есть ли разница, если приложение node.js запустить с cluster либо же 2 приложения в разных ядрах процессора?

Tags: node.js, многопоточность, микросервисы, cluster

Я хочу больше разобраться с node.js cluster и есть ли разница если запустить node.js приложение в главном потоке и выделить из cluster ещё одно ядро (как я понимаю - будет два неблокирующих процесса, пусть даже если на сервере одно ядро) или с другой стороны - взять создать два экземпляра микросервиса node.js - Какая разница в производительности и как лучше делать?

Comment: Если процессам не надо обмениваться данными, то разница лишь в том, что с cluster будет выделен один поток "координатор" и 2 рабочих процесса.

Comment: Описывал свое видение [многопоточности в node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-worker-threads-%d0%b8-cluster/1460929#1460929) - вопрос чем то похож. Там правда сравнение кластера с worker_threads. Однако, по сути, что отдельный поток, что воркер, особой разницы нет для понимания,  что и где лучше.