# Как сделать так. чтобы функция выполнялась на клиенте express js или в отдельном окне, чтобы сервер не зависал

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Есть веб приложение написанное на express. Проблема в том, что когда клиент нажимает кнопку, которая отвечает за выполнение долгой функции, сервер зависает и другой клиент не может ничего делать параллельно, пока сервер не закончит выполнение этой функции. (Она асинхронная, и сервер ждет её выполнения).

Я думаю, что есть несколько вариантов:

1. При нажатии на кнопку запускается отдельный терминал с этой функцией, а после записывает в файл результат. Клиент на своей стороне может посмотреть завершено или нет. Но нужно, чтобы это сразу происходило нажатием на одну кнопку запуска.
2. Может есть такая тема, когда функция выполняется на стороне клиента.
3. Слышал про многопоточность, если эта то, что мне нужно дайте знать.

Может есть уже готовое решение в express и я просто тормоз. Если да, подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Готов связаться с кем-нибудь, кто шарит в этой теме. Буду очень благодарен, спасибо)

Comment: Почитайте про [многопоточные варианты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-worker-threads-%d0%b8-cluster/1460929#1460929)

Comment: Кстати, если вы запустите тяжелую операцию на стороне клиента, то у вас зависнет клиент. В таком случае можно [воспользоваться webWorker'ами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: Что ж за функция такая АСИНХРОННАЯ - что сервер зависает и другой клиент ничего не может сделать?!

В моей практике было такое решение - была отдельная таблица под такие задачи, при запуске - все параметры сохранялись туда, в response сервер отдавал айди задачи. после этого запускался отдельный терминал который выполнял эту задачу и логгировал проценты выполнения задачи (ну и необходимые статусы/месседжи). Фронт энд когда получал статус айди - ломился на отдельный урл и с интервалом проверял статус выполнения задачи и получал месседж на каком этапе задача.

Comment: но вопросы остаются по асинхронной задаче - если каждый синхронный этап слишком долгий - что сервер зависает - необходимо задачу разбивать на куски.
Например массивы перебирать chunk'ами.