# Стоит ли вынести приложение NodeJS в отдельный docker контейнер?

Tags: node.js, docker, архитектура, centos7

Имеется приложение на Node JS, которое запущено в одном контейнере docker на сервере Centos 7.

Это приложение каждую ночь (c 1 часа ночи и до 7 утра) загружает большой массив данных (60Гб) и ежегодно прирост составляет +20Гб. То есть через 3 года будет где то 120Гб за этот промежуток. Так же загрузка любой части может происходить по запросу в любое время, в том числе и одновременно несколько частей.

Есть задача реализовать отгрузку данных по модели REST API (по объему вероятно где то 30Гб + прирост 10Гб в год), сторонней системе из той же базы MongoDB которая развернута на том же сервере.

Можно либо использовать имеющееся приложение загрузчика, либо создать новое (тоже NodeJS) в новом контейнере Docker.

Вопрос:

Правильно ли, что лучше создать отдельное приложение, так как будет задействовано уже 2 ядра процесса, вместо одного в однопоточном ассинхронном NodeJS? И задержек при одновременной загрузке/выгрузке нескольких крупных таблиц (5-20 Гб) из базы уже не будет?
Либо же никакой разницы не будет и внутри 1 приложения NodeJS можно реализовать несколько веб-сервисов которые слушают разные порты и загружают/отгружают данные максимально задействуя процессор и равномерно распределяя сетевой трафик внутри своих ассинхронных вызовов?

Comment: По ресту гонять 60Гб данных - ну так себе история. Подцепите ноду напрямую к БД. У NodeJS есть кластера и воркеры. Мое понимание в вольном изложении, [чем cluster от worker_threads отличается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-worker-threads-%d0%b8-cluster/1460929#1460929) В зависимости от решаемой задачи можно через них реализовать многопоточность. На сервер 100 ядер впихнули, 99 дочерних процессов создали и вперед, у вас 99 обработчиков и 1 поток оркестровщик.

Comment: обновление второй бд через event driven?